# Make developer story tab visibility private by default

Tags: feature-request, developer-story

So I started fiddling with jobs, added CV, specified education and then I noticed that it's public:

---

[image]

---

And it took me some time to figure out that visibility is controlled by this setting:

---

[image: Under the "Edit Profile and settings" tab in "Developer story preferences", the "Show the developer story" checkbox in the Privacy section.]

---

In my opinion it doesn't make any sense to make it public from start. It won't be completed (you have only option to specify one position and one education which is in many cases not enough), it may require work before it's ready, so make it private please.

If I miss some option upon initial submit which makes it somehow public, then make this option private by default.

Making naming consistent (public != show) and making "Visibility: Public" interactable (to change visibility or to jump to setting screen) as a bonus.

Comment: It might be better for it to explicitly ask the user to set the visibility when it's created. I can see other people being surprised that their Developer Story wasn't visible right away. 25% of the folks who responded to the last survey were students. Potentially there are many people who could create a story and not need to add more than one school or job.